# Android Display HTML in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry if this is obvious to everyone else but I am having a minor difficulty understanding how to display html inside my listview.

My list view is declared.

```
ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
```

I populate it (not shown) then set my listview here with an ArrayAdapter.

```
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchByFood.this, R.layout.new_list_view, foods));
```

Further down I create a new array of strings that I want to have bold tags in.  I then add this new array (called arr_sort) to the arrayadapter insdie a onTextChanged() method.

```
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchByFood.this, R.layout.new_list_view, arr_sort));
```

So now that my new Array of Strings has < b > tags in it.  How do I make my listview display the bold text?

Here is my new_list_view

```
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/grey2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="40dip"
/>
```

And here is my ListView part in my main layout.

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_green"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@color/green6"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
    </ListView>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override getItem method of the Adapter and do the following:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchByFood.this, R.layout.new_list_view, arr_sort){
     public Object getItem(int position)
     {
          return Html.fromHtml(arr_sort.get(position));
     }
};
```

Comment: The fact that this is the accepted answer is confusing. The answer by the OP, S.A.Jay worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

Ok, so Jitendra Sharma was had the right idea for my scenario, but I needed to override the getView method.  Or at least that is what worked for me.  Then in the getView method I was able to set my text to render in html.

```
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchByFood.this, R.layout.new_list_view, arr_sort)
            {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
                {
                    View row;

                    if (null == convertView) {
                    row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_view, null);
                    } else {
                    row = convertView;
                    }

                    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)));
                    //tv.setText(getItem(position));

                    return row;
                }

            };
            lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It seems like the correct thing to do, but android can not find "mInflater", any idea of what I should do ?

Comment: LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) Activity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      This is what I added to make this work. Change activity to whatever your activity name is.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a SimpleAdapter, here is the code that enables HTML on a TextView.

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {  
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {  
        if (data instanceof Spanned && view instanceof TextView) {  
            ((TextView) view).setText((Spanned) data);  
        } else {  
            ((TextView) view).setText(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(data))); 
        }  
        return true;  
        }  
    }  
);
```

Ref: [Link] (http://android.jreactor.com/2012/07/17/simpleadapter-spanned-html-fromhtml/)

Answer (score 1):

If all you wanted is to display some text where parts of the text should be bold, all you need is one TextView, and properly formatted text (with <b> added) and do the following:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

For more information on what TextView+Html can support, see [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility of loading your texts from strings.xml, adding the  tag there will automatically bold your text.
If however your texts are dynamic, you will have to create a [custom adapter](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx), and in it to set the text using `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourText));`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<Spanned> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(MyActivity.this, R.layout.row);
listAdapter.add(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
listAdapter.add(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use ksoap for html data from any database engine

```
yourVariable=String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(ic.getProperty(0).toString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rr.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titulos)
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row;

            if (null == convertView) {
                row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
            } else {
                row = convertView;
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)));
            return row;
        }
    };
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

This also works and is perphaps a lot simpler. First, pass your data from String[] to Spanned[]

```
Spanned[] myhtmldata = new Spanned[mydata.length];
for(int i = 0 ; i < mydata.length; i++) {
myhtmldata[i] = Html.fromHtml(mydata[i]);
}
```

Then declare the ArrayAdapter using the CharSequence parameter

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> linksadapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.textview, myhtmldata);         
setListAdapter(linksadapter);
```

Borrowed from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-beginners/vrUhNND0xN0)