# Android replace html entities inside Listview from database

Tags: android, html, listview

My first post, I'm currently in the process creating a simple android app that pulls data from a database and shows it in a list view. 90% of it is done except that the data its pulling from contains HTML entities. here's a sample sample of the database and cursor and all that layouts etc:

This is just a simple test app so i can learn (and will eventually morph into a proper app). The idea behind it is that when you select a product, it starts a new intent that gives details about that product (passing the product name or id to the next activity).

Here's my list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/product_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's

Here's the Code

```
  final Cursor dataCursor = database.query("products", fields, null, null, null, null, "_id desc", null);

  dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, dataCursor, fields, 
                    new int[] { R.id.product_name, R.id.product_desc });

  this.setListAdapter(dataAdapter);

  mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), Filter.class);
            intent.putExtra("product_name",dataCursor.getString(0));

            startActivity(intent);

        }
      });
```

Here's the problem... The in the database contains some html entities.

The data is basically like this:

```
table products:
________________________________________________
|  product_name    |  product_desc |    _id    |
------------------------------------------------
|Product1 Name&reg;| Super special |     1     |
|Product1 Name&reg;| Super special |     2     |
|Product1 Name&reg;| Super special |     3     |
|Product1 Name&reg;| Super special |     4     |
________________________________________________
```

What i'm tring to accomplish is that the ® entity actually gets converted to the 'Registered' symbol and shown in the list item.

I tried to apply what i found here [Android Display HTML in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678234/android-display-html-in-a-listview) but that didn't work (maybe because the person wasn't using a  cursor an just a string array, i dont know). (and obviously my experience isn't that great).

When i do a test, to show a simple toast when selecting a list item and using that together with the apache StringEscapeUtils it works great and the ® and any other html entity gets converted to the proper (r) symbol and it looks fantastic.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product Name is: " + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(dataCursor.getString(0)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fromHtml method in the Html Utility class. It will return a Spanned object which you can use to populate TextViews in your list.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)

Comment: and is that just simply overriding the getItem method for the cursor?