# Adding textivew dynamically to listview in android only shows references

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a textview dynamically to a listview as follows. I see items appearing in the listview but they show up like this

```
android.widget.TextView@44f076d0
android.widget.TextView@44f07b58
android.widget.TextView@44f07f50
etc...

   ArrayList<TextView> tv = new ArrayList<TextView>();
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
            TextView t = new TextView(this);
            t.setText("hi there");
            tv.add(t);

        }
        ArrayAdapter<TextView> wordAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                tv);

        this.articleListView.setAdapter(wordAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are passing off the ArrayList of TextView Objects in the parameter for what the Adapter should **display**. Therefore, your `tv` list Objects are having their `toString()` method called. `toString()` for TextViews will give you `TextView@number` so this is expected. Change your `tv` ArrayList to an ArrayList of `String`, don't make any new TextViews and just pass off that new String ArrayList instead of `tv`. Your text will display fine then.

Comment: I got it to work with ArrayList<String> but I needed html formatted text so I switched it to ArrayList<TextView>. How can I get html formatted text then?

Comment: You might want to look at creating a custom adapter of some sort. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678234/android-display-html-in-a-listview) may help.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort your arraylist

```
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```