# Trouble rendering HTML in android listview

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my list views render some simple  tags in a list view, here is my code:

```
package net.mikepearce.theagileguide.fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import net.mikepearce.theagileguide.R;
import net.mikepearce.theagileguide.ValueActivity;

public class ListManifestoFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the adapter based on the string-array
        String[] principles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.manifesto_values);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_values, principles )
        {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                View row;

                if (null == convertView) {
                    row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_values, null);
                } else {
                    row = convertView;
                }

                TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)));

                return row;
            }

        };

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // Get the list view
        final ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // When clicked, pass to new Activity with the position as a parameter
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Activity a = getActivity();
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ValueActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("value_id", position);
                startActivity(intent);
                a.overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Which I got, in part, from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695159/155227

I'm very new to Android Dev, so I'm not sure whether this is what I should be doing and, if so, where the mInflater is coming from, as I get an error.

Can someone help?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

`mInflater` should be a `LayoutInflater`. You should be able to replace `mInflater` with `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()`.

Answer (score 0):

use this code under View row;

```
LayoutInflater mInflater= ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
```

Comment: That will not work, as this code is in a fragment, not an activity, and there is nothing in the code there that I can see that is named `context`.

Comment: for that context u use ur Activityname.this or For fragment ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater() use getActivity().getLayoutInflater();